# how to test multiple conditions in <c:if> jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to check multiple conditions inside the `<c:if>` tag.
I am doing it like this

```
<c:if test="${role ne manager || role ne admin || role ne moderator}">
  System.out.println("this result will not display for manager, admin & mod");
</c:if>
```

But still, I am able to see the result for above roles

Comment: If you have single statement is it working? `role ne manager || role ne admin || role ne moderator` is not looks like proper statement

Comment: @ByeBye yes only first statement is working here

Comment: if `ne` is `not` you have to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with bool logic here:

```
<c:if test=${role ne manager || role ne admin || role ne moderator}>
```

If user is MANAGER this will be:
`0 OR 1 OR 1 = 1`
Same for ADMIN and MODERATOR

So you have to change it into `AND`

```
<c:if test=${role ne manager && role ne admin && role ne moderator}>
```

And message will be shown only when user has not any of specified roles.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>` tags to make conditional rendering in jsp using JSTL.

To simulate **if** , you can use:

```
<c:if test="YourCondition"></c:if>
```

To simulate **if...else**, you can use:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.enter=='1'}">
        burger. 
        <br />
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
        pizza. 
        <br />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

If you just want to output different text, a more concise example would be

```
${condition ? "some text when true" : "some text when false"}
```

It is way shorter than *c:choose*.